# Rendering PDF error font weight. Only <b> or <strong> is showing, others are blocks

Tags: html, css, rendering, dompdf

I have PDF rendering error font weight. Only texts with "b" or "strong" is showing, others, like paragraphs are weird blocks. If I just stream the PDF and preview, everything looks fine. But when I save the PDF **"OUTPUT()"** and open the PDF from the server, the characters with font-weight 400 wil not show up instead showing weird blocks. Does anyone have a fix for this? I am searching for almost 6 hours and can't find a solution.

**I have everything like:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

@font-face {
      font-family: 'Nunito';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
}

body {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif!important;
}
```

Comment: I will look into this.... In the meantime, I have heard of others having similar troubles that are caused by the particular font itself. Some fonts either don't support, or don't play nicely with font-weights.

Comment: May I ask what program are you using to open the PDF from the server?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Just Aptana. I have also PHPMailer. When send in attachment same error happens.

Comment: Ok, Just curious. Some people have had propblems with the document reader (in their case Adobe 9) attempting to use default fonts instead of document fonts. This has resulted in the display of anomalies instead of text. Their solution was to embed the font in the document viewer and disable the "use default fonts only" option. I will keep looking for other solutions.

Comment: Hmm I understand. I just need a quick fix for this font weight problem. On their GitHub problems page they never answer.

Comment: But whats more irritating is that not only the font that I am using is causing weight errors. It's just all sans fonts also the DejaVu font that is included with DOMPDF is causing the same error.

Comment: That's very strange indeed. If it's happening with all sans fonts, then it doesn't seem to be an embedded font issue. However, this post here shows how someone overcame the problem by installing dejavu-sans-fonts. ---https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3346

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes I saw that earlier today but thats not exactly like the weight problem, he was just missing the file of the font.

Comment: Then I must admit I am at a loss to explain it I will keep looking though. All I can add for now is that everything I have come across thus far points to either an embedding issue or an encoding issue with regards to the font.

Comment: That, or it is necessary to install different font sets for their respective weights. If this were the case for you, I would say the only "set" that is loading properly is the "strong" set.